# Return Everyday from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to fill in the dates between today and 30 days ago in mysql.

eg:

```
Date          Value
2015-08-05    1
2015-08-04    2
2015-08-03    0
......
2015-07-05    1
```

Below is mysql:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(units.price), 0) as price, DATE(units.solddate) as date, DAY(units.solddate) as day,
        (
            select a.Date 
            from (
            select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
            from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
            cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
            ) a 
            where a.Date >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
        ) as onemonth
        FROM (tables)
        GROUP BY date
```

However, I got this error: **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row** I understood this error.

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution by correcting your approach

```
SELECT
     `dates`.`date` ,SUM( COALESCE( `units`.`price` ,0 ) ) AS `price`
FROM
    (
--  Start of query for making dates
    SELECT
         `dates`.`date`
        ,CONCAT( `dates`.`date` ,' 00:00:00' ) AS `day_start_datetime`
        ,CONCAT( `dates`.`date` ,' 23:59:59' ) AS `day_end_datetime`
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
             DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL `intervals`.`days` DAY ) AS `date`
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                 ( `hundreds_place`.`num`   * 100   )
                +( `tens_place`.`num`       * 10    )
                +( `ones_place`.`num`       * 1     ) AS `days`
            FROM     ( SELECT 0 AS `num` UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) AS `ones_place`
                JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS `num` UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) AS `tens_place`
                JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS `num` UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) AS `hundreds_place`
            ) `intervals`
        HAVING
            `date` >=  DATE_SUB( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 30 DAY )
        ) `dates`
--  End of query for making dates
    ) `dates`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `units`
        ON `units`.`sold_date` BETWEEN `day_start_datetime` AND `day_end_datetime`
WHERE
    1
GROUP BY
    `dates`.`date`
ORDER BY
    `dates`.`date`
```

Comment: why? both achieve the same result.

Comment: This can be used for intervals as big as 1000 days which roughly is 33 months and can be easily extended for even bigger intervals .

Answer (score 1):

After getting better understanding of what you are trying to achieve , I have put together this `MySQL` query .

I have tested it and it worked for me .

```
SELECT
     `dates_table`.`date`
--  ,`dates_table`.`day`
    ,SUM( COALESCE( `units`.`price` ,0 ) ) AS `price`
FROM
--  Start of query for making dates_table
    (
        SELECT
             DATE( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL `intervals_table`.`days` DAY ) ) AS `date`
            ,DAY( DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL `intervals_table`.`days` DAY ) ) AS `day`
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  0 AS `days`
                UNION SELECT  1 UNION SELECT  2 UNION SELECT  3 UNION SELECT  4
                UNION SELECT  5 UNION SELECT  6 UNION SELECT  7 UNION SELECT  8
                UNION SELECT  9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12
                UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16
                UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20
                UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24
                UNION SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28
                UNION SELECT 29 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 31
        ) `intervals_table`
        HAVING
            `date` >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 30 DAY )
    )
--  End of query for making dates_table
    `dates_table`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `units` ON
            `units`.`sold_date` >= CONCAT( `dates_table`.`date` ,' 00:00:00' )
        AND `units`.`sold_date` <= CONCAT( `dates_table`.`date` ,' 23:59:59' )
WHERE
    1
GROUP BY
    `dates_table`.`date`
ORDER BY
    `dates_table`.`date`
```

The `units` table I have used for testing is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `units` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`price` int(11) NOT NULL
    ,`sold_date` datetime NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `units` (`id`, `price`, `sold_date`) VALUES
(1, 10, '2015-08-02 00:00:00'),
(2, 11, '2015-08-03 00:00:00'),
(3, 14, '2015-08-03 00:00:00'),
(4,  3, '2015-08-04 00:00:00');
```

Result

```
date        price
----------  -----
2015-07-07   0
2015-07-08   0
2015-07-09   0
2015-07-10   0
2015-07-11   0
2015-07-12   0
2015-07-13   0
2015-07-14   0
2015-07-15   0
2015-07-16   0
2015-07-17   0
2015-07-18   0
2015-07-19   0
2015-07-20   0
2015-07-21   0
2015-07-22   0
2015-07-23   0
2015-07-24   0
2015-07-25   0
2015-07-26   0
2015-07-27   0
2015-07-28   0
2015-07-29   0
2015-07-30   0
2015-07-31   0
2015-08-01   0
2015-08-02  10
2015-08-03  25
2015-08-04   3
2015-08-05   0
```